# iptables config works in one Centos 6 server but not another one

Tags: centos, iptables, centos6

This iptables script:

```
#!/bin/sh
service iptables stop
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

works as expected on a Centos 6.3 server (provided by VPSBlocks.com.au) but not a Centos 6.0 server (provided by VPSNine.com). By "works as expected", I mean that it at least allows incoming access to ports 22, 80 and 443. And by not working, I mean it doesn't allow access.

The one that works has the following /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Feb 27 19:10:38 2013
*filter
:INPUT DROP [3:453]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:52]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb 27 19:10:38 2013
```

whereas the one that doesn't work has the following /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Feb 27 11:28:36 2013
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb 27 11:28:36 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Feb 27 11:28:36 2013
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb 27 11:28:36 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Feb 27 11:28:36 2013
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb 27 11:28:36 2013
```

If I replace the non-working /etc/sysconfig/iptables with the one that works in the other server, it allows me to keep the current ssh connection, but when I try to get back in, I'm locked out.

Why would the exact same iptables config work on one server but not the other? Could the difference in minor versions of Centos (6.3 vs. 6.0) account for the different behaviour?

**Update:**
The Centos 6.3 server (one on which the iptables config works) uses iptables 1.4.7-5.1.el6_2.
The other server uses iptables 1.4.7-3.el6.

**Update:**
`iptables --list` returns the following on BOTH servers:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh,http,https state NEW,ESTABLISHED 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Update:**
When I login to the 6.0 server, I see this warning:

```
Warning: Unknown iptable module: nf_conntrack_ipv4, skipped
```

I'm not sure how to install this. Is it a kernel module? If so, it looks like I'm snookered.

Comment: I thing you may want to `iptables -Z INPUT` then `tcpdump -i ethX port 22` on CentOS 6.0 box (don't forget to replace ethX with actual iface name). Then try to connect via ssh. You should see packets coming in on tcpdump output. And take a look at counters with `iptables -n -L -v`. Thus you can see if packets come in and which rule is applying to SSH connections.

Comment: The issue has evolved a bit. There is still a server difference, but I narrowed it down to outbound TCP issues and posted a new question.

Answer (score 0):

iptables multiport is a module, check if it is installed at the target CentOS system.

Comment: I ran `cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches` on both servers and both seem to have multiport installed, although in both cases, it's listed twice. Not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you might need to `flush` all the tables in addition to the `filter` (-F), which defaults to the filter table.

```
  /sbin/iptables -F
  /sbin/iptables -t nat -F
  /sbin/iptables -t mangle -F
```

Then accept connections to already established sessions with the following line in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` right above the accept rule for the loopback interface.

```
 -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED, RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

You might also need to manually load the `nf_conntrack_ipv4` module with -

```
  modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

If the multiport is giving you a problem, you can add the ports individually for a test.